# API Connect shows Cannot GET error when updating schema

Tags: server, 16.04, permissions, mongodb

I have API Connect installed with mongodb connector over a remote server.

When I access the IBM API Connect through browser, all is fine, but when I go to DataSources where my DB is, and try to hit Update Schema button as shown in the image, an error occurs showing this:

Cannot GET /apim/dataSources/partials/dataSourceMigrate.html

P.S. I gave full permission for my project directory (/var/www/) with full ownership for www-data group and still the same.

Anyhelp would be appreciated.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwZCP.jpg)

Comment: try to restart the service :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to access your resource with `curl`? Perhaps even with a browser. Don't forget to add the right port. With curl you could do it from the box where the API connect is running. The curl command would be something like: 
`curl -X GET http://<host>/apim/dataSources/partials/dataSourceMigrate.html` (fill in your hostname)

A few things to try:

- Get the file from your desktop
- Get the file from the API box (probably you would need to `ssh` into that box)

If those steps succeed I wouldn't know from current info. In that case please dig through the logfiles of both API connect and mongodb, and post the lines relevant to your problem.

If the first step fails, than you know that you have to check your webserver. First place to look is the error.log and access.log of your webserver.

If the second step fails than it might be a connection problem. Look at `ping <host>`  output to see if the box can reach your webserver. Could also easily be a firewall issue.

Hope this helps,
Jeroen

Comment: The only error i can see is:

{"name":"API Connect","hostname":"xxxxxx","pid":2293,"loc":"microgateway:analytics","level":50,"msg":"not able to perform the handshake with APIM, error: [Error: can not load default private key]","time":"2016-09-16T10:19:15.053Z","v":0}

Any suggestions?

Comment: Oh and by the way, I cant see this file anywhere, and I cant even find any information about it on IBM's documents or anywhere else, so maybe the error I showed you can give you a hint about it? Thanks

Comment: I think this helps. The import part here is "can not load default private key". I would focus on that but not on the file, perhaps reinstall the key. It is presumably an RSA key. I do not know anything about IBM's system, I hope you can find the information you need in their documentation.

Comment: Am sorry but this didnt help.. Maybe an API Connect expert can give more information about the issue! @Jeroen

Comment: afraid so. Good luck with it! And please report back once you have find a solution